# Js object property not being modified

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function where it receives an object (called "card"). inside this function i wanna change the value of one of its properties but it doesn't change.
here is the function:

```
 function replaceImgsUrl(card){
    console.log("card: " , card);// prints card: {imgs:[]}
    card.imgs = "sex";
    console.log("new card: " , card); // prints new card: {imgs:[]}
    return card;
}
```

By the way i am using node.js , although i don't think it would make a difference.
Does anyone have an idea on why this could be happening?

Comment: If you want to push data into `card.imgs` array why not use `card.imgs[0] = 'sex';`?

Comment: it may be not a writable property

Comment: How is the object `card` defined? Possibly the object was frozen (with `freeze()`) or otherwise configured so that you cannot modify `imgs`. Maybe it would be OK for you if you would do `card.imgs.push("sex")`.

Comment: @ArchNoob i want to replace the value of the property "imgs", so after the assignment it should print: new card: {imgs:"sex"}

Comment: @PabloMarino https://jsfiddle.net/4j6acapL/ .

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how your `card` object was defined and if it was `freezed` or you are using [some kind of immutable library](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable) which will prevent you from mutating properties.
But otherwise it works fine as you can see here:

```js
 var myCard = {
  imgs: []
 }
 
 function replaceImgsUrl(card){
    console.log("card: " , card);// prints card: {imgs:[]}
    card.imgs = "sex";
    console.log("new card: " , card); // prints new card: {imgs:[]}
    return card;
}

replaceImgsUrl(myCard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working with an actual object as argument but looks strange. Why do you want to replace an object property which type is an array by a string ?

```js
function replaceImgsUrl(card){
  console.log("card: " , card);// prints card: {imgs:[]}
  // card.imgs = "sex";
  card.imgs.push("sex"); // Isn't it what you'd like to do ?
  console.log("new card: " , card); // prints new card: {imgs:[]}
  return card;
}

replaceImgsUrl({ imgs: [] });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `card` object was frozen with `Object.freeze()` or otherwise configured to not allow modifications to the object properties.

If you really want the `imgs` property to change from an array to a string, then you'd probably have no other way than to create a new object:

```
function replaceImgsUrl(card){
    console.log("card: " , card);// prints card: {imgs:[]}
    card = Object.assign({}, card); // get shallow copy
    card.imgs = "sex";
    console.log("new card: " , card); // prints new card: {imgs:"sex"}
    return card;
}
```

Note that only the returned value will have the object as you want it; the original object will not have changed.

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure but if you can't mutate `card` for some reason can you re-assign its memory?

Comment: You cannot assign to `imgs`, but you can *mutate* the `imgs` array, like with `imgs.length = 0` or `imgs.push("sex")`, `imgs[0] = "gender"`, ...etc.

Comment: i was referring to the `card` object. what if `card` is frozen or protected by some kind of library?

Comment: Well, that is what I said in my answer: it probably is (frozen), and it means that you cannot assign to the properties of `card` directly, nor add or delete properties. If you want that, you're without hope. The only way out is to create a new object.

Comment: yeah i know, i mentioned it in my answer as well. i'm wondering if you can or can't override the object and re-assign it with a new object. is there a way for a library to prevent you from doing so?

Comment: No, you cannot mutate it (not sure what you mean with "override the object"). Once you have it frozen, that's it. There is no way back. Of course, you can reassign to the object, but then you have a *different* object altogether.